# query cursor attribute from select statement

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, cursor

I am trying to set a where clause in a query which has a cursor as column.

```
with w1 as (
select 1 pid, 'a1' pnm from dual union all
select 2 pid, 'b2' pnm from dual 
), w2 as (
select 1 pid, 10 cid, 'aa1' cnm from dual union all
select 1 pid, 20 cid, 'bb2' cnm from dual union all
select 1 pid, 30 cid, 'cc3' cnm from dual union all
select 2 pid, 11 cid, 'dd4' cnm from dual union all
select 2 pid, 12 cid, 'ee5' cnm from dual 
), w3 as (
select l.pid, l.pnm,
       cursor(select d.cid, d.cnm from w2 d where d.pid = l.pid) a  
  from w1 l
) 
select * 
  from w3 
 where a.cid = 11
```

this gives `ORA-00904: "A"."CID": invalid identifier`
Is it even possible to create a where clause like that ?
ver: Oracle 11gr2

Comment: No, that nested cursor is going to have to be processed via `fetch` statements before the data can be accessed. [this article](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/1879.cursor-expressions-usage) explains the use of cursor expressions quite well.

Comment: yeah, I used same example to create that one :).

Comment: TBH I hadn't come across cursor expression until I read your question.  I think it's fair to say they are not commonly used.

Comment: I think cursor expressions return refcursors, so if you were really interested, you could create a function which opens the refcursor and returns a sql table, and then you could use `where exists (select 1 from table(my_function(a)) where cid = 11)`. (I haven't tried it though.) See part 2 of this post: https://community.oracle.com/thread/888365

Comment: i just wanted use only select statement, otherwise it easy to do it with object types or xml query.